# Как лучше сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"В коллективе часто берет на себя функции неформального лидера, тайного контролера за ситуацией..." — как тут лучше сказать: "контролера за ситуацией" или "контролера ситуации"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, что слово КОНТРОЛЁР требует родительного падежа существительных: "тайного контролера ситуации".

КОНТРОЛЁР, а, м., одуш. [фр. contrôleur].Должностное лицо, которое контролирует кого-что-нибудь.Яндекс.Словари › Толковый словарь иноязычных слов, 2004

КОНТРОЛЁР, а, м. [фр. controleur].
Служащий, на обязанности которого лежит контроль, проверка чьих-н. действий или прав.Железнодорожный к. К. сберкассы. Театральный к. Таможенный к.
Яндекс.Словари › Толковый словарь Ушакова, 1935-1940

Спасибо за вопрос. В связи с ним очень полезно вспомнить о слове КОНТРОЛЬ, которое вызывает трудности при употреблении.  ***Поможет статья из справочника Розенталя "Управление в русском языке":***
**Контроль** *за чем,  над кем-чем и чего*.  1 .  з а ч е м и н а д ч е м  (при отглагольных
существительных).  Контроль за  (над)  выполнением плана.  Контроль за  (над)  расходова-
нием средств.  2.  з а  ч е м  (при существительных,  обозначающих действие или признак). 
Контроль за работой станка.  Контроль за качеством работы.  Контроль за порядком в
классе.  3.  н а д к е м- ч е м (  при существительных отвлеченных и при одушевленных су-
ществительных).  Контроль над финансами.  Контроль над производством.  Контроль над
молодыми специалистами.  4.  ч е г о  (в официальной и профессионально-технической ре-
чи). Контроль деятельности выборных органов). Контроль температуры в доменной печи. 
Контроль готовой продукции.